# Increase in the mean of the error when increasing polynomial degree

Tags: time-series, least-squares, error, fitting, polynomial

I'm working on some data which is a time-series of measurements with values around $1.5*10^8$ (small variations, around 1000)

Basically, I compute a model for my data, with a polynomial of this form : $$\ a_0 + \sum_{i=0}^{n}  a_i*x^{(2*i-1)} $$

But when I do the least-square estimation of the coefficients for different values of n i start getting strange results for n > 12 (and it goes crazy for n = 15), where the mean of the error starts increasing when the number of parameters goes up which seems counter-intuitive.

I have tried to normalize the time-values, I've tried to go through singular value decomposition, and I've tried to increase the precision of the computer. But I still get the exact same results. Can it be normal results ? (Also then why does it get crazy at n = 15 ?).

I'm wondering this because it doesn't fit the pattern that I was taught where with more parameters you get closer to the data and you have to use a test to know when you're over-fitting.

Here is how the mean of the error evolves:
[image]

Here are some fits that I get:[image]
[image]